# boost asio asynchronous udp client, handler never triggered

Tags: c++, asynchronous, boost, udp, asio

I've been struggling with this for almost 2 weeks now and I think it's time for me to
ask for help.

I need to get data from a server running on a fpga. The server has been written
by someone who's unfortunately no longer working with us. Though the server
works as expected because when I send a request I can see with wireshark the
expected content. Wireshark is running on the computer that executes the c++ udp
client.

The five first lines (1..5) in the table are the ones I send. Every other lines,
out of ICMP ones, are sent by the server. The server send messages over multiple
ports according to the type of message. I think sending data is properly working
otherwise I would not get line 6 to xxx.

The problem is that my client never receives anything. The handler is never
triggered and I can't find why.

Can you please help me one this one.

Thank you very much for your time.

Olivier

| "No." | "Source" | "Destination" | "Protocol" | "Length" | "Info" | "port" |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| "1" | "192.168.0.254" | "192.168.0.1" | "UDP" | "50" | "44702 → 5 Len=8" | "1" |
| "2" | "192.168.0.254" | "192.168.0.1" | "UDP" | "50" | "44702 → 5 Len=8" | "2" |
| "3" | "192.168.0.254" | "192.168.0.1" | "UDP" | "50" | "44702 → 5 Len=8" | "3" |
| "4" | "192.168.0.254" | "192.168.0.1" | "UDP" | "50" | "44702 → 5 Len=8" | "4" |
| "5" | "192.168.0.254" | "192.168.0.1" | "UDP" | "50" | "44702 → 5 Len=8" | "5" |
| "6" | "192.168.0.1" | "192.168.0.254" | "UDP" | "60" | "50000 → 32776 Len=8" | "6" |
| "7" | "192.168.0.1" | "192.168.0.254" | "UDP" | "74" | "51000 → 32776 Len=32" | "7" |
| "8" | "192.168.0.254" | "192.168.0.1" | "ICMP" | "102" | "Destination unreachable (Communication administratively filtered)" | "8" |
| "9" | "192.168.0.1" | "192.168.0.254" | "UDP" | "466" | "52000 → 32776 Len=424" | "9" |
| "10" | "192.168.0.254" | "192.168.0.1" | "ICMP" | "494" | "Destination unreachable (Communication administratively filtered)" | "10" |
| "12" | "192.168.0.1" | "192.168.0.254" | "UDP" | "474" | "52000 → 32776 Len=432" | "12" |
| "13" | "192.168.0.254" | "192.168.0.1" | "ICMP" | "502" | "Destination unreachable (Communication administratively filtered)" | "13" |
| "14" | "192.168.0.1" | "192.168.0.254" | "UDP" | "474" | "52000 → 32776 Len=432" | "14" |
| "15" | "192.168.0.254" | "192.168.0.1" | "ICMP" | "502" | "Destination unreachable (Communication administratively filtered)" | "15" |
| "17" | "192.168.0.1" | "192.168.0.254" | "UDP" | "474" | "52000 → 32776 Len=432" | "17" |
| "18" | "192.168.0.254" | "192.168.0.1" | "ICMP" | "502" | "Destination unreachable (Communication administratively filtered)" | "18" |
| "19" | "192.168.0.1" | "192.168.0.254" | "UDP" | "474" | "52000 → 32776 Len=432" | "19" |
| "20" | "192.168.0.254" | "192.168.0.1" | "ICMP" | "502" | "Destination unreachable (Communication administratively filtered)" | "20" |
| "22" | "192.168.0.1" | "192.168.0.254" | "UDP" | "474" | "52000 → 32776 Len=432" | "22" |
| "23" | "192.168.0.1" | "192.168.0.254" | "UDP" | "474" | "52000 → 32776 Len=432" | "23" |
| "24" | "192.168.0.1" | "192.168.0.254" | "UDP" | "474" | "52000 → 32776 Len=432" | "24" |
| "25" | "192.168.0.1" | "192.168.0.254" | "UDP" | "474" | "52000 → 32776 Len=432" | "25" |
| "26" | "192.168.0.1" | "192.168.0.254" | "UDP" | "474" | "52000 → 32776 Len=432" | "26" |
| "27" | "192.168.0.1" | "192.168.0.254" | "UDP" | "474" | "52000 → 32776 Len=432" | "27" |

```cpp
#include "udp_client.hxx"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
//#include <thread>
#include <boost/bind/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <ctime>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
#include "udp_constants.hxx"
using  boost::asio::ip::udp;

udp_client::udp_client(boost::asio::io_context &io) :
  io(io),
  socket(io)
{
  datagrams.push_back(std::vector<unsigned char>{0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00});
  datagrams.push_back(std::vector<unsigned char>{0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x7a, 0x11, 0xfe});
  datagrams.push_back(std::vector<unsigned char>{0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x02, 0x00, 0x7a, 0x11, 0xfe});
  datagrams.push_back(std::vector<unsigned char>{0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x05});
  datagrams.push_back(std::vector<unsigned char>{0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01});
  filename="/home/lemaire/data.dat";
  set_acquisition_and_get_data(datagrams);
}


udp_client::~udp_client()
{
  socket.close();
  // close file
  output_stream.close();
  // inform user
  std::cout << "udp server destructor" << std::endl;
}


std::vector<unsigned char> udp_client::ui64_to_vector(uint64_t w)
{
  std::vector<unsigned char> vec(8, 0x0);
  char c;
  size_t d{0};
  for(int i{0}; i<8; i++)
  {
    d = (8-1-i)*8;
    c = static_cast<unsigned char>(w >> d);
    vec[i] = c;
  }
  return vec;
}

bool udp_client::send_data(std::vector<std::vector<unsigned char>>& datagrams)
{
  std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
  udp::resolver resolver(io);
  udp::endpoint endpoint_tx =
        *resolver.resolve(udp::v4(),
                          udp_constants::ip::fpga,
                          "5").begin();
  try
  {
    std::cout << "send data" << std::endl;
    socket.open(udp::v4());
    for(auto datagram: datagrams)
      socket.send_to(boost::asio::buffer(datagram), endpoint_tx);
  }
  catch (const boost::system::system_error& e)
  {
    std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
  }
  socket.close();
  return true;
}

bool udp_client::set_acquisition_and_get_data(std::vector<std::vector<unsigned char>>& datagrams)
{
  std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << " begin" << std::endl;
  send_data(datagrams);
  start_receive();
  return true;
}

void udp_client::start_receive()
{
  std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
  output_stream.open(filename,
                     std::ofstream::out |
                     std::ofstream::trunc |
                     std::ofstream::binary);
  try {
    socket.open(udp::v4());
  }  catch (std::exception& e) {
    std::cerr << "erreur ouverture: " << e.what() << std::endl;
  }
  receive_data();
  std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << " socket data started" << std::endl;

  return;
}

void udp_client::receive_data()
{
  std::cout << "socket opened: " << socket.is_open() << std::endl;
  socket.async_receive_from
      (boost::asio::buffer(recv_buf),
       endpoint_rx,
       boost::bind(&udp_client::handle_data, this,
                   boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                   boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
  std::cout << "async receive from started" << std::endl;
}

void udp_client::handle_data(const boost::system::error_code& error,
                             std::size_t bytes_transferred)
{
  std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
  if(!error)
  {
    output_stream.write(recv_buf.data(), bytes_transferred);
    receive_data();
  }
  else
  {
    std::cerr << "handle daq start error: " << error.message() << std::endl;
  }
  return;
}
```

```cpp
// file: udp_client.hxx 
#ifndef UDP_CLIENT_HXX
#define UDP_CLIENT_HXX
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/system/error_code.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/strand.hpp>
#include <boost/bind/bind.hpp>
using  boost::asio::ip::udp;

class udp_client
{
public:
  udp_client(boost::asio::io_context& io);
  ~udp_client();

  void handle_receive(const boost::system::error_code& error,
                      std::size_t bytes_transferred);
  void start_receive();
  static std::vector<unsigned char> ui64_to_vector(uint64_t);
  bool send_data(std::vector<std::vector<unsigned char>>& datagrams);
  bool set_acquisition_and_get_data(std::vector<std::vector<unsigned char>>& datagrams);
private:
  // strand
  boost::asio::io_context& io;
  std::vector<std::vector<unsigned char>> datagrams;
  std::string filename;
  udp::socket socket;
  udp::endpoint endpoint_rx;
  std::ofstream output_stream;

  boost::array<char, 128> recv_buf;

  std::list<std::vector<char>*> buffer;
  void handle_data(const boost::system::error_code& error,
                   std::size_t bytes_transferred);
  void receive_data();

  const std::string get_data_file_name();
};

#endif // UDP_CLIENT_HXX
```

```cpp
// file: main.cxx
#include "udp_client.hxx"
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <signal.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/thread_pool.hpp>
int main()
{
  try
  {
    boost::asio::io_context io;
    udp_client client(io);
    boost::thread t{boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_context::run, &io)};
    io.run();
    t.join();
  }
  catch (std::exception& e)
  {
    std::cout << "erreur" << std::endl;
    std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say hello in my message...

Comment: The good news is, saying hello is [not desired/required](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). [SO] is not a forum, but accumulates questions with answers, so we appreciate you being to the point.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the table of UDP responses (and assuming your C++ programs runs on 192.168.0.254 alright) you should probably bind to port 32776 (which is 0x8008), so e.g. in `start_receive`:

```
socket.open(udp::v4());
socket.bind({{}, 0x8008});
```

That works for me with a simplistic test driver:

```
netcat -u localhost 32776 -w 0 <<< '01234567'
```

And that prints e.g.:

```
bool udp_client::set_acquisition_and_get_data(std::vector<std::vector<unsigned char> >&) begin
bool udp_client::send_data(std::vector<std::vector<unsigned char> >&)
send data
void udp_client::start_receive()
socket opened: true
async receive from started
void udp_client::start_receive() socket data started
void udp_client::handle_data(const boost::system::error_code&, std::size_t)
socket opened: true
async receive from started
void udp_client::handle_data(const boost::system::error_code&, std::size_t)
socket opened: true
async receive from started
...
```

etc. Also, the data.dat file then contains:

```
00000000: 3031 3233 3435 3637 0a30 3132 3334 3536  01234567.0123456
00000010: 370a                                     7.
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. I modified my client and the weird thing is that the data coming from the fpga don't trig the handle. But when I send data with nc `echo -ne test | nc -u "192.168.0.254" 32776` it looks like it's working since I enter the handle...

Answer (score 0):

I'm so sorry... It was just a firewall issue...
I switched the connection from public to trusted zone and now, I receive the data. At least when the client is run standalone (simple udp_client + main).
When I try to run it in a qt application, it does not trigger the handle.